# Putting some lines in a script to execute them in gdb

Tags: bash, firefox, gdb

I want to create a script or actually a shortcut to surf in peace

```
#!/bin/bash
konsole -e firefox --debug
(gdb) handle SIGPIPE noprint nostop pass
(gdb) handle SIGSEGV noprint nostop pass
(gdb) run
```

this doesn't work. i hope someone will help me. after the solution, i can tell you story. it's possible that i will help a lot of people with that.

so far i can do this:

creating a bash-script with

```
#!/bin/bash
konsole -e firefox --debug
```

marking it as executable. double click ends with opening up in terminal waiting for me to type run and enter

creating the `~/.gdbinit` with following content

```
handle SIGPIPE noprint nostop pass
handle SIGSEGV noprint nostop pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Here Documents of `bash` (`<<`) to pass the interactive commands to `gdb`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
firefox --debug  <<'EOF'
handle SIGPIPE noprint nostop pass
handle SIGSEGV noprint nostop pass
run
EOF
```

Check the `Here Documents` section of `man bash` to get more idea.

**Example:**

```
$ cat scr.sh 
#!/bin/bash
firefox --debug <<'EOF'
help
quit
EOF

$ bash scr.sh 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/firefox/firefox...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) (gdb) (gdb) (gdb) (gdb) (gdb) (gdb) List of classes of commands:

aliases -- Aliases of other commands
breakpoints -- Making program stop at certain points
data -- Examining data
files -- Specifying and examining files
internals -- Maintenance commands
obscure -- Obscure features
running -- Running the program
stack -- Examining the stack
status -- Status inquiries
support -- Support facilities
tracepoints -- Tracing of program execution without stopping the program
user-defined -- User-defined commands

Type "help" followed by a class name for a list of commands in that class.
Type "help all" for the list of all commands.
Type "help" followed by command name for full documentation.
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Command name abbreviations are allowed if unambiguous.
(gdb) 

$  ##Back to prompt
```

Comment: i've to still write run and press enter. i'm not sure if gdb recognizes the "handle"-lines

Comment: @user371780 I don't know about the `handle` lines but this is the generic approach and should work..

Comment: There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" 
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/firefox/firefox...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb)

Comment: terminal stops after (gdb) like it does everytime and waits for me to type run and press enter. i need some lines in a script that does it for me.

Comment: @user371780 check my example..perhaps you should add a `quit` line at the end..

Comment: alright it works. now i know how to create a new line here. it's shit + enter. only for edit mode. maybe 4 spaces work....
    just 600 characters wtf?
    this is the code:
    #!/bin/bash
    firefox --debug <<'EOF'
    handle SIGPIPE noprint nostop pass
    handle SIGSEGV noprint nostop pass
    run
    EOF
no need of "konsole -e"......then just double click the script, then gdbinit can be deleted

Answer (score 0):

alright it works. now i know how to create a new line here. it's shift + enter. only for edit mode. maybe 4 spaces work....
    just 600 characters wtf?

```
this is the code:
#!/bin/bash
firefox --debug <<'EOF'
handle SIGPIPE noprint nostop pass
handle SIGSEGV noprint nostop pass
run
EOF
```

no need of "konsole -e"......then just double click the script, then gdbinit can be deleted

thank you heemayl. you saved the life of many, many frustrated linux users who's firefox crash are too damn high! i'm sorry for adding the text above, but konsole -e is not neccessary, which was mine fault. i am now really curious what EOF means.

Comment: This is what i have stated in my answer..isn' t it? so you should probably remove this answer as you have already commented below my answer containg this..

Comment: Now the backstory is that long time ago many many year, I couldn't use firefox as I did on Windows. I didn't know what to do so I accepted this problem. Now I want a solution. First I read about segmentation fault, the GDB. I tried to memtest my RAM but everything is ok. I marked the bad RAM in BadRAM of grub2 but still no help. Then I started Firefox in gdb (I did earlier too to detect the bad RAM nodes) but this time I added some block commands. If SIGSEGV or SIGPIPE occurs, just go on. Now after so many years, I can live in pease and surf in peace and freedom! Thank you!

Comment: quit and console -e are unneccesary

Comment: while running from shell, if you want to run the script in a new terminal window than `konsole` is needed..and i added `quit` later to be sure of the operation after your initial comment..

Comment: btw my badram grub2: GRUB_BADRAM="0x00007ffff18ee587,0x00007ffff7bcb95b,0x00007fffdfbb3a24,0x00007ffff7bcc20b,0x00007ffff7bc1c45,0x7ffff2b6c726,0x7fffe60fe700,0x7fffa71f2000,0x0000555555564f00,0x7fffcf261700,0x7fffb42b4000,0x7fffb3f37000,0x7fffcb488000,0x7fffba61e000,0x7fffa62df000,0x7fffa73c2000,0x7fffc3526000,0x7fffcc7b1700,0x7fffe5cfe700,0x7fffbb7ea000,0x7fffc659f000,0x7fffc53ac000,0x7fffbb8c7000,0x7fff9869e000,0x7fffbcf75000,0x7fff98d48000,0x7fffbc182000,0x7fff9a342000,0x7fffbe36c000,0x00007ffff1325ae2,0x7fffb0b4f000,0x00007ffff18d5b0b,0x7fffd6d80700,0x00007ffff20cb689,0x7fffcaafd700"

Comment: Do you have any additional query? If so please ask it as a new question..we will be happy to answer..also i would suggest you to remove this answer as i have made the necessary modifications to my answer..